# HTACCESS Rewritten URLS are redirecting query parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have rewritten my urls from the following: eg

https://website.com/search.php?number=00000000000

to the following:

https://website.com/number/00000000000

But now I wish to pass ?success=1 to my rewritten urls. But it just redirects and ignores it:

eg

https://website.com/number/00000000000?success=1

to

https://website.com/number/00000000000

How can I achieve this?

Here's my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

#redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^number/([^/]*)$ /search.php?number=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: could you give us some working demo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my fault, i was doing a header location redirect and not appending and query params in the redirect